# Websocket/SignalR stops receving data consistently on low-end machine

Tags: websocket, signalr

I am testing our software on a low-end laptop, and I am running into a really odd issue with websocket (with signalR) disconnecting with too many messages being sent.

When bulk sending the messages by aggregating the data into fewer messages, instead of many messages, the client does not seem to disconnect. However, when sending individual messages (10-20 per sec), the client seems to almost instantly time out on the first send or keepalive or client -> server message.

The laptop experiencing the issue has 8GB ram, and an I3-1215U CPU with Windows 11.

- The issue occurs on Firefox, Edge, and Chrome.
- The issue occurs with or without a VPN to different locations around the world.
- Hosting the service on a raw EC2 machine with no load balancers does not resolve the issue.
- The issue doesn't seem to occur when hosting the server locally on the same network.
- The issue doesn't seem to occur on higher-end devices.
- Whether the client processes or ignores the messages has no effect. (I completely removed the .on for the signalR socket).
- The issue doesn't seem to be related to sending messages back to the client, it still dies after a couple of seconds whether a keep alive (or another client -> server is sent or not)

Here is a screenshot of the websocket data right before it disconnects. It's always right before a client->server packet.

It happens at random times, anywhere between 1-30 seconds after starting to receive the data.

[image]